# Finding $\iint_D y \ dA$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, jacobian

Let $D = \mathbf{\Phi}\left(\mathcal R\right)$ where $\mathbf{\Phi}\left(u,v\right)=\left(u^2,u+v\right)$ and $\mathcal R=[4,8]\times [0,4]$.

Calculate $$\iint\limits_D y \ dA$$

Note: It is not necessary to describe $D$.

I think you set the $x$ and $y$ bounds of the integral to $[0,4]$ and $[4,8]$ respectively and then set $x=u^2$ and $y=u+v$, but I'm not exactly sure. A walkthrough of the problem will be helpful.

Comment: There's no screenshot attached. Could you type up the question in Mathjax?

Comment: I think you should be interpreting $\mathcal R$ to be the region$$\{(x,y)\mid x\in[4,8],y\in[0,4]\}$$and not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is incorrect, because the region in coordinates $(x,y)$ is  $\mathcal{D}$, not $\mathcal{R}$. In other words, $\mathcal{D}$ is the region you obtain by transforming $\mathcal{R}$ via $\Phi$, which you are implicitly told that it refers to coordinates $(u,v)$. The idea is there, though, and I'll try my best to explain it without solving the whole thing.

---

I realized that my previous answer was totally wrong, as it basically assumed that the change in $(x,y)$ is linear as in $(u,v)$ which is in general NOT true, and not true in this case. I am sorry to have posted a low quality answer and now answering properly.

---

Revisiting the question, the underlying trick is that you can transform the domain in coordinates $(x,y)$ to coordinates $(u,v)$ by knowing the effect of the transformation $\Phi$. Here I show how to do that.

Basically, the transformation $\mathcal{D}=\Phi(\mathcal{R})$ implies that differential areas in $\mathcal{D}$ relate to differential areas of $\mathcal{R}$ through the rate of change in $\Phi$, i.e. its Jacobian. The Jacobian of $\Phi$ corresponds to
$$\begin{align}
J&=\left|\det\left(\begin{bmatrix}\frac{dx}{du}&\frac{dx}{dv}\\\frac{dy}{du}&\frac{dy}{dv}\end{bmatrix}\right)\right|\\
&=\left|\det\left(\begin{bmatrix}2u&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\right)\right|\\
&=|2u|=2u
\end{align}$$
where the last equality comes from the fact that $u$ is already positive. Then,
$$\int_{\mathcal{D}}y\,\mathrm{d}A = \int_{\mathcal{R}}J\cdot y(u,v)\,\mathrm{d}A_{\mathcal{R}}=\int_{\mathcal{R}}2u(u+v)\,\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v$$
where you know the integration limits.

Comment: @MusicTheorist68 please see the edited version, as the initial answer was wrong.